# how to generate Normally distributed random number?

Tags: functions, normal-distribution, random

I am looking for a function that can generate Normally distributed random numbers. I came to know about bux-muller transform but I didn't understood it completely what it is doing. Thus it would be good if some one can suggest how to generate Normally distributed random numbers?

Comment: Have you seen the description in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution)? If you do not want to use $\sin\,$ and $\cos,\,$ you can use the Marsaglia polar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So box muller transform can generate normally distributed random numbers from uniformly distributed random number.
I found my answer here:

http://www.design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/Gaussian.html

http://www.random.org/gaussian-distributions/